# Can access WIndows partition in GUI but struggling through terminal

Tags: permissions, mount, fstab, devices

I have Windows and Ubuntu installed. I'm today cleaning up my home directory and noticed there is a downloaded file I want to move to my Windows partition. I don't want to use GUI. I know it works. Nautilus appears to mount the partition with Windows on it so I can access it. Doesn't teach me anything about using the power of GNU/Linux from the terminal. Upon trying `cd /dev/nvme0n1p2` it says `bash: cd: /dev/nvme0n1p2: Not a directory`. I'm guessing this is because it's not an actual device but pertains to symbolise one ie like a symlink? Upon doing `ls -lh /dev/n*p2` it appears in the permissions column with a b which means block, correct? I thought with it being a block ie a device like a drive it could be mountable. I run `mount /dev/nvme0n1p2` and it says `mount: /dev/nvme0n1p2: can't find in /etc/fstab`. Upon trying to navigate to it Ubuntu doesn't want to treat /dev/nvme0n1p2 like a directory. And I can't seem to get to the point where the file representing this block can be accessed as a directory like when you might connect an external HDD and it is mounted ready to be accessed.

I thought if I mounted that partition I would be able to access it as it seems like that it what the system is doing upon allowing me to access my Windows partition. I'm clearly missing a fair chunk of the process out here and so would appreciate any advice. I also saw bits about fstab in my playing with sshfs whereby it appeared I could configure fstab to mount remote file systems upon startup and maintain persistence. I can't see that being required in order to simply access the partition temporarily without it being mounted everytime I run Ubuntu. I'm still learning so appreciate I may be well off the mark. As the returned error status shows the partition is not found in fstab, which is confusing me.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 /mnt
```

or more advanced, if you want to mount more than one extra file system,

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/mp1
sudo mkdir /mnt/mp2
...
```

and mount to one of these new mountpoints, for example

```
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 /mnt/mp2
```

and then you can copy to/from the directory `/mnt/mp2`

You will need `sudo` to copy into that directory unless you modify its ownerskip and/or permissions.